# How to know what button clicked?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I create two fragments:

```
 <fragment
    android:name="BoxFragment"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/box_fragment_1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/box_fragment_2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"     
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_box" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/box_fragment_2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"        
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_box" />
```

Layout of this fragments:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="197dp"
    android:layout_height="197dp"
    android:id="@+id/ibPress"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

So, i register OnClickListener:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_box, container, false);

    ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibPress);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG,this.toString());
           //how to know,wich button clicked?
           presenter.onButtonClick(...?);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

So, i want to know from what fragment button was pressed?
Should i need to reference View into `presenter.onButtonClick`?
At presenter, i want to know what button was pressed and then do some work.

Thank you!

Comment: Should there not be a "name" tag also for the second fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your  `presenter.onButtonClick()` by 
 `presenter.onButtonClick(int fragmentId)` or  `presenter.onButtonClick(String fragmentTagName)`
Then in that method using `switch case` you can perform the action based on the id or tag of that particular fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `id` of the currently clicked view using `getId()`.See the code below.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
          // it was the first button
          break;
        case R.id.b2:
          // it was the second button
          break;
      }
  }
}
```

Please read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId()) for more info.

Comment: I don't think that Admiral meant this. His query is different.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari  not so sure..might be.. Let the op respond..we'll wait until then.. :p